# Using an excel vlookup with wildcards

Tags: excel-formula

I have a large data source that I cannot edit - so I cannot insert or modify any columns. I have a large serial number, about 15 digits long, and I am only concerned with the 9th, 10th and 11th digit which tells me what the product code is.

So I'm trying to do some sort of vlookup that allows me to search for the 3 digit product code I have within the large serial number.

Say my code is 333 and the serial number is 000101903339098. I want to do a vlookup with 333 as the lookup value and find all the products that have 333 in their serial numbers.

Any ideas how to do this?? I think I have to use some sort of wildcard character but I'm unsure how do that

Comment: If the "333" appears specifically at the 9th, 10th and 11th character, then use `????????333*` in the `VLOOKUP` function - like `=VLOOKUP("????????333*",A:A,1,FALSE)`

Comment: The above will only work if the data in Column A is stored as text and not a number that is formatted to display 15 digits.  Also it will always only return the first match and not all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an array formula you can get it all in one cell.

```
{=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A2:A9,7,3))=E1,B2:B9,""))}
```

[image]